# Using a specific library depending on the OS version

Tags: android, aar

I have 2 libraries (they are doing the same thing but one is for api 16 and second for api 21).
I would like to use it dependently on user android api version (but I do not want to use flavors).
Is it possible, to load them somehow dynamically?

Comment: Are the classnames and packages the same in each, or are they different? This doesn't sound like a very good library if it's the former.

Comment: I know, but I have to use it. They are rather the same.

Comment: Why not just use the API 16 library? Anyway, this is usually exactly what product flavors are for.

Comment: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    // Call some material design APIs here
} else{}

I dont undertand your requirment very much but i answered accroding to what i predicted

Answer (score 0):

Import both in your project and when you publish your app, do it as a bundle, so the play store will choose which one to include in the relevant apk depending on the user. Read more about [App Bundles on the developer's website](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/). Then in your project use annotations to target each API and differentiate your code using Build.VERSION.SDK_INT

Comment: my project has minApi19 so when I tried to implement library in v21 I have error "minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library". I'm more than happy to use bundle but how to import both libs?